# strtotime to convert both date and time

Tags: php

can anyone advise how i would convert a date like "Tuesday, 22 June, 2010 00:00" to a unix timestamp using strtotime()? I need to also store the hours and minutes and it's not clear if is best done using strtotime. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the second `,`, `strtotime()` will currently not understand your date/time format (remove it and it will work properly).

If you have a static format for the date, using `strptime()` or `DateTime::createFromFormat()` are more reliable, and will allow other non-datetime strings in the date to be present as long as you've defined them.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("l, j F, Y H:i","Tuesday, 22 June, 2010 00:00")->format("c");
```

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I haven't used DateTime::createFromFormat before - very useful.

Comment: Should be noted that the DateTime methods are only available in PHP 5.3+, however if you take a look at the PHP documentation most methods have "alternatives" in the comments.

Comment: Most `DateTime` methods are available since 5.2, howver, you are correct the `DateTime::format` is available since 5.3, which is now over a year old.

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does convert both date and time. It converts a string to a [Unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).

> **What is the unix time stamp?**
>
> The unix time stamp is a way to track
>   time as a running total of seconds.
>   This count starts at the Unix Epoch on
>   January 1st, 1970. Therefore, the unix
>   time stamp is merely the number of
>   seconds between a particular date and
>   the Unix Epoch. This is very useful to
>   computer systems for tracking and
>   sorting dated information in dynamic
>   and distributed applications both
>   online and client side.

http://www.unixtimestamp.com

You can convert a unix timestamp back to a string using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` and `date` can be used to convert to a UNIX timestamp and extract portions of that timestamp respectively.

The combination should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Tuesday, 22 June, 2010 00:00";
$dateString = substr($string,0,-5);
$timeArray = explode(':',substr($string,-5));
$timeStamp = strtotime($dateString) + 60*$timeArray[0] + $timeArray[1];
```