# PHP - Transform Date

Tags: php

I have the following date and time in an RSS feed:

```
Fri, 01 Oct 2010 12:26:57 +0000
```

However I just want to display:

```
Fri, 01 Oct 2010 12:26:57
```

There should be a really simple way to do this in PHP, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert one date into another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

Comment: Here is a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337088/strtotime-to-convert-both-date-and-time

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind showing the date in UTC/GMT (I forget which), then just use substring to strip off the `+0000`. However, if you want local time, you'll have to convert the string to a timestamp and then format the timestamp back to a date string.

```
$uncleandate = 'Fri, 01 Oct 2010 12:26:57 +0000';
$timestamp = strtotime($uncleandate);
$cleandate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$clean_string = str_replace(" +0000", "", $your_date_string);` should do the job

see [str_replace doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)